# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: servlets

Can someone please tell me why am I getting this error, I have done endless search on web and tried all sorts of suggestions nothing seems to be working.
Error:- HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

```
@WebServlet("/LoginProccess")
public class LoginProccess extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    DbConnection dbConn = null;
    Connection conn = null; 
    CallableStatement proc = null;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // get the variables entered in the form
    String clientID = request.getParameter("cid");
    String loginID = request.getParameter("lid");
    String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
    String instName = request.getParameter("iName");
try{    
    dbConn = new DbConnection();
    conn = dbConn.connection();
    proc = conn.prepareCall("{call pa_internal_admin.fu_login(?,?,?,?)}");
    proc.setString(1, clientID);
    proc.setString(2, loginID);
    proc.setString(3, password);
    proc.setString(4, instName);
    proc.execute();
    response.sendRedirect("adminHome.jsp");
    proc.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());      
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
} finally {
    // Always close the database connection.
    try {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ignored) {
        out.println(ignored);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont change the visibility modifier

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
```

Consider to change to

```
 protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was a long night and a very frustrated one I was trying all sorts of silly things. I have changed the modifier back to 'protected' it hasn't made any difference.  Any suggestions

Comment: Please let me know what url are you using probably you are hitting  another url

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some mistake in post method, like you are type `public`. But, you should must change `protected`. First of all you must preview the code before to posting your question.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
    DbConnection dbConn = null;
```

Difference between public and protected:

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
public      |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✔
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✘
```

Comment: After all that struggle I deleted the bloody servlet and created a new one with a different name and it's working.

Comment: No unfortunately it didn't, I've had it as   protected before but out of frustration I was trying all sorts of silly things. I replaced it back to   protected but still no joy.